# JDBC equivalent to hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I am looking for an alternative to `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers` for jdbc in order to generate SQL with quotes (to escape reserved keywords) around table names.

We are migrating an oracle database to an h2 in-memory database, and one of the tables is named LIMIT, which is obviously a keyword and bad practice but unfortunately we do no have control over the database structure and it is not something that can be changed.

I found [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.jdbc.usage.doc/topics/jdbc_enable_quoted_identifiers.html) page that *suggests* that is can be done on a transactional level, but we need it to be applied globally.

Comment: Maybe check if this article is of any help to you. https://vladmihalcea.com/escape-sql-reserved-keywords-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: JDBC does not generate SQL nor does it parse the SQL you pass to the API calls. so there can't be such an option (and _if_ there is such an option, it would be specific to the driver, not something that "JDBC" supports).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for that clarification, I was not aware of this. Do you mind adding this as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?